# What do comparison operators compare on arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison-operators

I was surprised to find the comparison of two arrays to return a boolean in JavaScript.

```js
var blah = [1,2,3];
var blah2 = [2,3,4,5];

document.write(blah < blah2);
```

I was honestly expecting NaN, but in every browser I tested I got a consistent "true" result.  I couldn't find any documentation on what comparison operators do with arrays in JS.  What is being compared in this case?

Comment: The arrays are coerced to string values, which essentially means that `.join()` is called and the results are compared.

Comment: You were expecting *NaN* as the result of the less-than operator? So you do think things like *42 is NaN than 666*?

Comment: The comparison operators never return `NaN`, they always return a boolean. `NaN < NaN` returns `false`.

Comment: @Pointy if you put that as an answer I will select it.

Comment: @TobotRobot thanks - I've been looking for a duplicate, but I can't find a good one. We really need a comprehensive, understandable uber-question for "Mysteries of JavaScript relational operators".

Comment: I was also trying to find a comprehensible explanation of this in the ECMAScript spec. But it looks like it's buried in the details of `@@toPrimitive`.

Comment: A second look at the ECMA script docs does show NaN is not allowed, but undefined is.  I guess I misread that documentation and meant undefined.  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was honestly expecting NaN

No. A comparison always returns a boolean in javascript (when it doesn't throw an exception).
If any of the operands is not comparable (like `NaN`), it would return `false`.

> What is being compared in this case?

The [abstract relation comparison algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) converts all arguments to primitive values to compare them. In the case of your arrays, this will cast them to strings, so you're essentially comparing

```
"1,2,3" < "2,3,4,5"
```

Comment: Although it returns `false` when I try it with a `NaN` argument, the spec says it should return `undefined` in this case.

Comment: @Barmar: The abstract algorithm returns `undefined`, so that the actual operator can always return `false` (regardless whether it's `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=` that invokes the algorithm)